# Slow loading of combined and compressed JS/CSS on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari

I'm running a .NET MVC Singe Page Application that combines and compresses all CSS/JS files when deploying. Compressions are done by Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier. Combination is done "manually" by writing one big file.

It's all good except for mobile Safari. Whenever I reload the page e.g. on the Ipad 2 (IOS 9), loading takes a long time (about 5-10 seconds) but then works as expected.

When i switch of the combination and compression it takes about half a second to load as it does on any other browser with compression...

CSS file size is ~70kb, JS file size is ~ 220kb

I've already tried to set a line-threshold (500,2000, etc.) for the created files but nothing worked so far.

Comment: I've solved the Problem. When Combining the scripts to one big file, i added some linebreaks "\r\n". Safari seems to not like them...